# Use the same keystore in more than one app (Android)

Tags: java, android, flutter, keystore

I have an application on Google Play, which was made in Java and I performed all the procedures until uploading there, so this application already has a keystore. After a month I redid the entire app using Flutter, but I would like to publish this app as an update of the app that is already available, in fact it is the same, only redone in another language, but I am having problems while storing keys, because I am trying to use the key for the same application already published and the following message appears "keystore file not defined for configuration release flutter signature". So I would like to know how do I use the same key in both apps and if they have any other way for me to publish this new version without having to launch another app.

I'm also having this error when I run the `flutter build apk -v`

```
[        ] WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
[        ] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[   +2 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[   +3 ms] 439 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 429 up-to-date
[ +663 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 316,6s, longer than expected)
[   +7 ms] "flutter apk" took 322.180ms.
[   +6 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

My key.properties:

```
storePassword=*********************de
keyPassword=*****************cme
keyAlias=key
storeFile=\Users\Pedro\Desktop\Music Me Items\key_musicme\musicme_upload.jks
```

Comment: Have you followed these steps? 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: @ASADHAMEED Yes, but I only use the part to reference the keystore, since I don't need to create a new one because I already have one.  The same problem is in the referencing, which is showing that the password is wrong and I am using the same passwords.

Comment: Have you seen this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787510/flutter-issue-keystore-file-not-set-for-signing-config-release

Comment: Have you update flutter version number in `pubspec.yaml`? I can see the version conflict warning!

Comment: Yes I already tried for that question, and about changing the version, I only changed the version of the app, but insist on saying that the password is wrong.  Can I build from Android Studio?

Comment: I would recommend you follow all the steps listed by flutter except for generating the `key` as you already have one.
See this one as well,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965909/keystore-password-was-incorrect-when-building-appbundle-flutter